# Circular Navigation rotation

Tags: jquery, navigation

I'm working on a circular navigation system, and I have a spinner in the centre which rotates on hover using the JqueryRotate 2.2 Plugin, however I was curious as to how to make it repond better? When hovering over Portfolio it doesn't move because I want the arrow to stay vertical upon loading, but you'l notice when hovering over about > Contact and then Blog it kinda looks bad, probably because I've set it to rotate at -90 degrees, but is there a way so that the spinner goes to the button the quickest way? so if its at contact, then it will rotate 90 degrees from there rather than from Portfolio?

Its live at `http://www.anthonyeamens.co.uk`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could `.getRotateAngle()` to see if it should be `-90` or `270`

```
$("#blog").hover(
 function () {
      if($("#spinner").getRotateAngle() < 10)
          $("#spinner").rotate({animateTo:-90})
      else
          $("#spinner").rotate({animateTo:270})
      },
       function () {
          $("#spinner").rotate({animateTo:0});

});
```

Comment: it works! however there seems to be some odd behaviour when hovering over the other buttons, when I go from contacts to blog your code works a treat, but when I go back to contacts it then spins 270 degrees, but then if I do the same procedure it works perfectly. =S is it possible for the spinner to move according to what is been hovered?